# Where does `ss` set up flex input to come from command line arguments?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, iproute

I heard that [`ss` uses Bison to parse command line arguments](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ssfilter.y). Bison takes input from output Flex. Flex takes input from stdin by default. Where does `ss` set up flex input to come from command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Bison calls `yylex()` whenever it needs a token. The return value of `yylex()` is a small integer, which is either one of the enumeration constants declared with `%token` in the bison grammar, or a character constant other than 0, or 0 to indicate EOF.

`yylex()` must also:

- Save the token's semantic value in the global variable `yylval`, if the token has a semantic value; and
- Save the token's location in the input stream in the global variable `yylloc`, if the parser actions make use of location information.

You can build a scanner using the `flex`  command line tool. But you are under no obligation to do so. You could use a different tool to generate a scanner. Or you could define a `yylex()` function yourself. The interface for the scanner has been kept as simple as possible to simplify implementation.

Many tools, including `ss`, use bison with a hand-coded lexical analyzer. So the answer to your question is that `ss` never sets up the flex input because it doesn't use flex. (The fact that this is possible does not necessarily make it a good idea. Many hand-written scanners are significantly slower than `flex`, and the code is verbose and hard to reason about.)

---

#### Other intetfaces

The above is the default interface between `yyparse` and `yylex`. There are alternatives:

- You can define `yylex` to take additional arguments, if your `yylex` implementation requires additional data. Normally, these additional arguments will be provided to `yyparse()` so that the parser can use them in its call to `yylex()`. See the [bison manual section on the `%param` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-_0025param).
- You can tell bison to generate a pure parser which does not rely on global variables, in which case it will call `yylex` with a pointer to a semantic object and, if location information is used, a pointer to a location object. See the [bison manual chapter on pure parser interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Calling).
- You can request a "push parser", which is called by the scanner every time a token becomes available. See the [bison manual chapter on push parsers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Push-Parser-Function).